# Vue prop is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I fetch data in my App.vue. I split it up, then hand them out to my components as props. However, the data meant to go in my chart.js is undefined, and when I console.log it to see what it's structured like I get a ton of observers around it, so I can't find out whats going on. Whenever I try to log what I want in there it returns undefined. I wrote an if statement that checks if this.agentTickets isn't undefined, which returns true.

Did googling and theres a lot of issues with undefined props, but I didn't quite get an answer out of the ones I read.

App.vue (fetching, defining and passing prop)

```
<div>
   <AgentStats v-bind:agent-tickets="agentTickets" />            
</div>

data() {
    return {
        activeTickets: [],

        newTickets: [],

        completedTickets: [],

        agentTickets: []
    }
},

fetch('/api/scotttickets')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resJson => {
            this.agentTickets = resJson
});
```

AgentStats.vue (Will load in chart and fill data)

```
name: 'AgentStats',
components: {
    BarChart
},
props:['agentTickets'],
data() {
    return {
        agentData: null
    }
},
mounted() {
    if(this.agentTickets !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('Er zit wat in hoor')
    }
    this.fillChart()
    console.log(this.agentTickets)
},
methods: {
    fillChart() {
        this.agentData = {
            //labels: [this.agentTickets[0]]
        }
    }
}
}
```

The data I am fetching:

```
{"scottsTickets":{"agent":"Scott","activeTickets":1,"onHoldTickets":0,"unreadTickets":0}}
```

So now when I try to show this.agentTickets.scottsTickets it returns undefined, I want this to give back the array, so I can make the chart data reactive.

Comment: Where do you define `agentTickets` in a `data: {}` property?

Comment: I edit with how my data looks like!

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you have a `-` in the prop identifier. `:agent-tickets="agentTickets"` Remove the dash, I also found this as an issue.

Comment: No, according to the documentation this is the way to write it. Furthermore, I had this issue before editing the prop identifiers to kebab case

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm saying I had the same issue when using kebab case -> camelCase and it was what worked for me.